# Data Binding ObservableCollections with an IoC

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am writing a Universal app targeting Windows 8.1, and am re-writing it to use an IoC container.  However, I found something that is puzzling me a bit.

Before I used the IoC, I would create an instance of my VM in the code-behind and bind to it, like this:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" DisplayMemberPath="Title"  />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private MainPageVM Data = new MainPageVM();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = Data;
}
```

**MainPageVM.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList { get; set; }

public MainPageVM()
{
    ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
}
```

This worked just fine.  However, now I am setting up the app very differently, like this:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private IUnityContainer _Container;

public App()
{
    _Container = new UnityContainer();
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    _Container.RegisterType<MainPage>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    _Container.RegisterType<Frame>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    _Container.RegisterType<MainPageVM>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(typeof(Frame),
                                 typeof(MainPage)));

    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        rootFrame = _Container.Resolve<Frame>();
        rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        var mainPageVM = _Container.Resolve<MainPageVM>();
        mainPageVM.Show();
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

This creates an instance of `MainPageVM()`:

**MainPageVM.cs**

```
private Frame _Frame;
private Page _View;

public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList { get; set; }

public MainPageVM(
    Frame frame, 
    Page view)
{
    _Frame = frame;
    _View = view;

    _View.DataContext = this;

    ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    OnPropertyChanged("ItemList");
}

public void Show()
{
    _Frame.Content = _View;
    Window.Current.Content = _Frame;
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

MainPage.xaml is not changed.

My question is, why do I have to signal `OnPropertyChanged("ItemList");` to activate the binding in the second version, but not the first?  Am I doing something wrong here?

My entire repository can be found on GitHub: [Learn OneNote](https://github.com/Hosch250/LearnOneNote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between these two lines should fix this:

```
_View.DataContext = this;
```

and

```
ItemList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
```

What happens is that you currently first set the DataContext, which causes all of the view's bindings to reevaluate, and only then you modify `ItemsList`. Since `ItemsList`'s setter doesn't call `OnPropertyChanged`, the view is not updated when it's changed. By switching between the lines, you first initialize the data context and only then reevaluate bindings.

A more readable solution would be to include a call to `OnPropertyChanged` in your setter (then you don't have to switch the lines):

```
private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> itemList
public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ItemList
{
    get { return itemsList; }
    set
    {
        if (itemsList != value)
        {
            itemsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
        }
    }
}
```

Although it's always a good practice to first initialize your data context and only then set it to avoid having controls to attempt binding twice.

Comment: ObservableCollections are observable, so they trigger updates automatically.

Comment: @Hosch250 ObservableCollections implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and notify when an item has been added or removed from the collection. If you want to get notified when the entire collection instance changed, you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your DataContext and raise the property changed event for that property.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the first version, ItemList instantiated in view-model constructor which itself constructed in view's initialization, before data binding. But in the second version, data get's bound first, then you instantiate the ItemList.